# Update IONIC not working (windows)

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to update ionic-cli to 1.7.1 i run this command

```
npm uninstall -g ionic 
npm install -g ionic
```

and this

```
npm update -g ionic
```

but it won't update , when i run

```
ionic
```

it shows the version 1.6.5

what's wrong ? and how to fix it ?

i'm on Windows 10

[image]

Comment: `npm install -g ionic` should be enough to update ionic-cli ? aren't you getting errors while updating?

Comment: no , there is no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inject this line of code in your bower.json file and run `bower update`

```
"ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.1.0",
```

Comment: the line is alredy exists